# Can I use the Asp.Net Core shared runtime from .Net Full Framework app?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-runtime

I have an Asp.Net Core 2.2 application built using .Net Full Framework (4.6.2) libraries.
This is done to maintain compatibility with some shared libraries used by my company.
When I publish my web site I get the "standalone" distribution: I have a 100-ish of Microsoft.* and System.* dlls included in my app.

I read that with .Net Core one can choose Framework-dependent deployments in order to keep application and framework separate.

So, the question is simple: **can I distribute my application with only the non-Microsoft dlls and target the already installed Asp.Net Core runtime assemblies**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what Net Standard was created for; to bridge the gap

Comment: I can't see how this answers to my question. I am using .Net Core, at least the Asp.Net Core libraries. And they are bridged using netstandard dll. The thing is: do I have to distribute the Core dlls with my app or can I use a system installed .Net Core/Asp.Net Core installation?